# Could not deduce error type

Tags: haskell

we have to write a code, which will sort the elments of a list.

For this , we have to use two help functions. 
In my case calculate (gives the max/min of a list) and delete ( will delete the max/min).

And what a suprise, it is not working ;).

Running the code , I am always getting:" could not deduce (Ey (a-> a-> Bool)) arising from a use of 'sort'"

Any suggestions?

```
sort p [] = []
sort p ls = selected : sort p (delete)
 where
  selected =  calculate p ls
  calculate p ls
                | p == < =  minimum ls
                | otherwise = maximum ls
  delete = del selected ls
  del selected ls = filter (/= selected) ls
```

Comment: this will not even compile - are you sure it's the code you have?

Comment: how are you supposed to run this (what is `p`)?

Comment: also the very last line is wrong if you don't want to have your sorted list the same length as before (for example `[1,1,1]`)

Comment: It was my attempt at solving the task.

Comment: ok so you want to sort descending or ascending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version that should be close to your idea (taking the *least* element of the list and then sorting the rest):

```
import Data.List (delete)

sort :: Ord t => [t] -> [t]
sort [] = []
sort ls = selected : sort (delete selected ls)
 where selected = minimum ls
```

that will not shorten a list:

```
λ> sort [2,4,6,1,2,5]
[1,2,2,4,5,6]
```

the idea to take in a function to decide if you want to sort descending or ascending can be done like this:

```
import Data.List (delete, minimumBy)
import Data.Function (on)

sort :: Eq t => (t -> t -> Ordering) -> [t] -> [t]
sort _ [] = []
sort p ls = selected : sort p (delete selected ls)
 where selected = minimumBy p ls
```

example:

```
λ> sort (compare) [2,4,6,1,2,5]
[1,2,2,4,5,6]
λ> sort (compare `on` negate) [2,4,6,1,2,5]
[6,5,4,2,2,1]
```

of course this is not really a good sorting-algorithm

---

now you should go over your version again and think how you can fix it - for example there is a way to use `maximum` to get the list sorted descending instead

---

#### using `(<)` and `(>)`:

the idea is then to basically rewrite `minimum` and use the *compare* function you pass on:

```
import Data.List (delete, foldr1)

sort :: Eq t => (t -> t -> Bool) -> [t] -> [t]
sort _ [] = []
sort p ls = extremum : sort p (delete extremum ls)
  where extremum  = foldr1 (\ a b -> if p a b then a else b) ls
```

example:

```
λ> sort (<) [2,4,6,1,2,5]
[1,2,2,4,5,6]
λ> sort (>) [2,4,6,1,2,5]
[6,5,4,2,2,1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I guess , I'm not allowed to use minimumBy, 'delete' and 'on'. I changed < to 2, just to see if it would compile. Beside  looking really ugly, it does ;) . But it will not work with '<', '>' or just plain <, >.

Comment: it will not work this way - you cannot compare functions (and even if the syntax would be `(<)` for the function) - I don't know what you are allowed to use but you don't have to use the second version - just use a parameter (you `2` would do - or use `Bool` or some self-defined sum-type) to decide if you want to use `minimum` or `maximum` - I did not do because I wanted you to have some thought (it's homework after all)

Comment: btw: if you are not allowed to use `delete` you can either stick with your `filter` version (which might be okay) or try to define it yourself - usually it's one of those functions you'll see in an introduction course anyway (it's not hard to write using the usual recursive pattern-match)

Comment: I tried, but i don't get it. What should I do if sort ( < ) [ 2,5,3,7] => [2,3,5,7]?

Comment: again - you cannot use `(<)` as a switch - what you can do is `sort True [2,5,3,7] = [2,3,5,7]` and `sort False [2,5,3,7] = [7,5,3,2]` and the way you can do it is basically use my first version and then either use `maximum` instead of `minimum` for `False` or just `reverse` if `False` ...

Comment: But we have to use (<) . the task explicitly says it.

Comment: well ok I'll do it for you (the trick is to rewrite minimum I guess)

Comment: ok I served you everything on a plate there - you probably have to work a bit to get the things you are not allowed to use out but at least the idea should be clear

Comment: Awesome. it also helped me to understand the foldr function much better.